# What is the best way to analyse (in SPSS) a matched group design?

Tags: anova, t-test, multilevel-analysis, matching, psychology

I am studying cognition in juvenile sex offenders.

I have two independent groups: juvenile sex offenders and juvenile non-sex offenders. I am matching these groups on 9 variables: age, gender, SES, education, IQ, treatment, ethnicity, mental health and medication. They will be tested on scales of self-esteem and self-efficacy and their skin conductance will be measured also.

I was advised to do a matched t-test but obviously this is rather simple, so I was then told to do a multi-level ANOVA using the control variables as levels. Which analysis is best? And how would I do the ANOVA?

Comment: Are you creating matched pairs? If so, the paired t-test is the way to go. The matching is controlling the 9-variables, so you don't need to control for them in the analysis (i.e., they are controlled by design).

Comment: Not matched pairs as this may be too challenging/time consuming... just a matched group design.

Comment: If they are not paired, then you can't do a paired t-test. Explain how you are going to match the groups.

Comment: Ok so I am unsure of my own logic here but the general idea was to code the demographic variables. For example: Age would be categorised into 6 (12-18years); Gender into 2 (M/F); SES into 3; Education 5; IQ 7; Ethnicity 5; Mental health 2; Medication 2.

Also with regards to the variables of interest: self-efficacy will be delivered twice (past/current); self esteem delivered twice, and galvanic skin response taken at baseline and during each scale (both times).

Comment: I didn't answer that very well. Essentially I am recruiting 100 participants from each group; obtaining their demographic details; and matching by removing odd/extreme outliers. (I need 88 participants from each group for a moderate effect size, and so I can essentially remove up to 24 participants who do not fit the matched group design).

Comment: So you are not matching a priori as part of the research design but rather post hoc at the analysis stage. Thus, you aren't really matching but rather doing statistical adjustments. ANOVA/ANCOVA or regression analysis are your main option (they will all give the same result).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Do you think that I have too many variables? Or is it feasible?

Comment: Depends on your sample size.